# Functional equation: $f(2x)=f(x)+f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: functional-equations, inverse-function

I have been working to find solutions to the functional equation
$$f(2x)=f(x)+f^{-1}(x)$$
$$f:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$$
So far I have found the trivial solution
$$f(x)=x$$
and, by mere luck, I stumbled upon the solution
$$f(x)=\ln(e^x-1)$$
But I don't know how to go after this problem strategically without using "guess and check". Can anybody find any other solutions, or show me how I might find the second solution that I mentioned analytically, without just getting lucky and happening across it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is no here, functional equations in general are difficult to handle, compound this with the inability to make any claims regarding symmetry (e.g. $x \to -x$) or $x = 0$ as a special guess (which is outside your domain). I'm guessing trial and error is the best you can hope for here.

Comment: Another "trivial" solution (for $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$) is $f(x) = -x$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah, good point.

Comment: I can show that the only solutions that are analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$ 
are $x$ and $-x$.

Comment: I thought the domain is restricted to the positive reals?

Comment: I'd still be interested to see the proof though.

Comment: You might also try $f(x) = a \ln(e^{x/a}-1)$ for $a > 0$.

Answer (score 5):

As requested by Gregory, here is the proof that the only solutions analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$ are $x$ and $-x$.

Rearranging and applying $f$ to both sides, we get the functional equation
$$ f(f(2x) - f(x)) = x \tag{1}$$
Taking $x=0$ (assuming this is in the domain) we get $f(0) = 0$.
If $f$ is differentiable at $0$, differentiating both sides of (1) at $x=0$ gives
$f'(0)^2 = 1$, thus $f'(0)= \pm 1$.

Now suppose $f$ is a solution of (1) that is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$ with $f'(0) = 1$.  If $f(x)$ is not $x$, there exist some integer $m > 1$ and constant $a \ne 0$ such that
$f(x) = x + a x^m + O(x^{m+1})$.  Then the left side of (1) is is
$f(x + (2^m-1) a x^m) = x + 2^m a x^m + O(x^{m+1})$

Similarly for the case $f'(0)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe plugging $x=f(x)$ can help. 
$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$

$f(2f(x))=f(f(x))+x$
$ \implies 2f^{'}(x)f^{'}(2f(x))=f^{'}(x)f^{'}(f(x))+1$

Comment: Probably a stupid attempt, but commenting on questions and suggesting something is not possible for me, commenting being disabled.